# Generating and merging all combinations of multiple lists python

Tags: python, list, permutation

Similiar questions to this one have been asked before, but none exactly like it an and I'm kind of lost.

If I have 2 sets of lists (or a lists of lists)

```
listOLists = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2]]
listOLists2 = [[4,5,6],[4,6,5]]
```

And I want 'merge' the two lists to make

```
mergedLists = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,3,2,4,5,6],[1,2,3,4,6,5],[1,3,2,4,6,5]]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations Or combinations will get you started.

Comment: neither is correct. `itertools.product` is needed

Answer (score 1):

You may use generator to simplify your code, like this:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3]]
b = [[4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [5, 4, 6]]
c = [i + j for i in a for j in b]
print c
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5], [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6], [2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 1, 3, 4, 6, 5], [2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6]]
```

Comment: Indeed, but extend will extend the content of raw list, which may be undesired :).

Comment: There is no generator in this answer

Comment: @SebastianWozny, isn't `[i + j for i in a for j in b]` a generator? In my studying course, such expression is called generator.

Comment: Then i would switch the course. `[i + j for i in a for j in b]` is a list comprehension, `(i + j for i in a for j in b)` is a generator

Comment: Wait, aren't they two  totally same thing, they share common attribute and member function, the only difference is that the content of `(i for i in a)` can't be modified after generating.

Comment: There is a very big difference between the two. The only common element is that they are both iterable.

Comment: We're off the question -_- as official remind, you can insist on your opinion, so do I. This is just conception which won't stay in mind while coding, and different understanding make no side effects.

Answer (score 1):

```
list1s=[[1,2,3],[3,2,1],[2,2,2]]
list2s=[[3,3,3],[4,4,4],[5,5,5]]


for indis1 in list1s:
    for indis2 in list2s:
        print(indis1 + indis2)
```

try and;

```
[1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4]
[3, 2, 1, 5, 5, 5]
[2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
[2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4]
[2, 2, 2, 5, 5, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [[1,2,3],[1,3,2]]
list2 = [[4,5,6],[4,6,5]]

mergedLists = []

for list1_inner in list1:
  for list2_inner in list2:
    mergedLists.append(list1_inner + list2_inner)

print(mergedLists)
```

Answer (score 0):

A comparison of methods:

```
import itertools
import random
l1 = [[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)]for _ in range(100)]
l2 = [[random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)]for _ in range(100)]
```

#### With `itertools`:

```
def itert(l1, l2):
    [list(itertools.chain(*x)) for x in itertools.product(l1, l2)]
```

#### With for loops:

```
def forloops(list1, list2):
    mergedLists = []
    for list1_inner in list1:
      for list2_inner in list2:
        mergedLists.append(list1_inner + list2_inner)
```

#### With a simple Comprehension:

```
def comp(l1, l2):
    [i + j for i in l1 for j in l2]
```

#### Speed

```
%time itert(l1, l2)
Wall time: 99.8 ms

%time comp(l1, l2)
Wall time: 31.3 ms

%time forloops(l1, l2)
Wall time: 46.9 ms
```